# Windows Server 2003 Stop: error code c0000139 entry point not found

Tags: windows-server-2003, enterprise

Getting Blue Screen on Windows Server 2003 Enterprise loading:

> STOP: c0000139 {Entry Point Not Found}
>   the procedure entry point
>   gdiGetBitmapBitSSize could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   gdi32.dll

I tried to copy `gdi32.dll` to `\windows\system32\` and `\windows\servicepackfiles\i386\` but makes no sense.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Problem was caused by unfinished installation of Service Pack.
I tried many suggestions from all over the internet, but only solution was to **Repair** system from the boot.

If you'll have same problem, don't forget to install Service Pack update right after repairing.